# Motion sensor programming for Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

I just got hold of a PDA (Samsung Omnia i900) with an embedded motion sensor (accelerometer) and would like to code something that would exploit this feature.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the Samsung Accelerometer API for Windows Mobile devices
http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=2&cntsId=4600

Answer (score 2):

Although this may not match your device, here is an [article](http://blog.enterprisemobile.com/2008/07/using-htc-diamonds-sensor-sdk-from-managed-code/) using an HTC accelerometer in managed code...

EDIT: This API has been [updated](http://wmpoweruser.com/?p=1232) to support the Samsung Omnia.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no common public API for WM devices that have accelerometers.

If a WM5 or WM6 device has an accelerometer, any API will be device manufactor specific like the HTC API.

I beleave (and don't take my word on this), that Mircosoft are planning a common accelerometer API for WM7.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion. Maybe you could design a game where you have small balls that can be brought to the centre of a maze by tilting the PDA at different angles.

Answer (score 0):

instead of a game why not develop a hour glass??? U can use this for fun and tracking time as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with reference to microlocation if you have a GPS receiver in your device. You could for example set tasks for rooms you have to accomplish in your appartment and then when you walk into your room you get a message (for example "clean the room"). Such concept would be good for companies as well for task management. 
Before doing this you should write an algorithm to reduce location errors by reading GPS data and accelerometer data which is also interesting.